# Calling an oracle stored procedure from IBM API Connect

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, apiconnect

We are exploring is there any way we can connect to oracle database and once the db connection is established how to access the stored procedures from IBM API Connect. As we are working on the Proof of Concept on this as per the client requirement (the current requirement is that in the client environment the team is accessing oracle stored procedures using WESB and now the client wants to move out of WESB and asked us to explore is there any possibility to access the oracle stored procedures from IBM API Connect). Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Oracle expert, but API Connect knows how to talk HTTP(S)--not SQL or anything like that.

So, you would need to have some layer between API Connect and your Oracle DB that can accept an HTTP request and then run the desired stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will try as you suggested.